# ng-if="hideDiv" , where hideDiv = false does not hides div

Tags: angularjs

I have to hide a div on click .

```
<div ng-if="hideDiv">
<div>text text text text</div>
<a ng-click="hideMe(false)">Click Me To Hide</a>
</div>
```

Controller

```
this.hideMe = function(action){
 $scope.hideDiv = action;
}
```

tested results are

```
console.log($scope.hideDiv) // Is false

{{hideDiv}}  <!--Is false-->
```

But still ng-if doesn't hide div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the snippet below. I'm pretty sure your problem is due to some angularJS configuration failure

```js
(function(){
    angular.module("app", []).controller("testController", function($scope)
    {
        $scope.showDiv = true;

        $scope.hideMe = function(IsVisible)
        {
            $scope.showDiv = IsVisible;
        }
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
    <div ng-if="showDiv">
        <a ng-click="hideMe(false)">Click Me To Hide</a>
    </div>
</div>
```